# Agregar option a un select a partir de un json

Tags: javascript, json

Estoy tratando de añadir más `<option>` a un `<select>` a partir de un archivo json.

Este es el formulario donde quiero agregar los `<option>`:

```
<div class="input-field col s12" id="materias">
                <select id="recargado" name="materias">
                    <option id="disabled" value="" disabled selected>Elige la materia a consultar</option>
                    <?php require_once("materias.php"); ?>
                </select>
                <label>Materia que deseas consultar</label>
            </div>
```

Tengo el siguiente código de JavaScript:

```
$("#carrera").change(function () {
let carrera = document.getElementById("carrera").value;

$.get("materias.php", { idcarrera: carrera })
  .done(function (json_data) {
    json_data = JSON.parse(json_data);
    var options = '';
    $.each(json_data, function (i) {
      console.log(json_data[i].clave);
      $('#disabled').append($('<option>').text(json_data[i].nombre).attr('value', json_data[i].clave));
    });
  });
});
```

El problema es, que no puedo añadir los `<option>`. Así como tengo el código, me pone todos los nombres de las materias, en el mismo `<option>`. Si cambio el `$('#disabled')` por `$('#recargado')`, no me añade nada. Sin embargo, si pongo `$(#materias)`, me pone el resultado de `json_data[i].nombre` como options sueltos, sin ningún select. ¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

Answer (score 1):

Hice un pequeño cambio en el `.each()`, donde le paso el array de materias que probablemente utilizas iterandolo para obtener la clave, además de que el `.append()` lo puse en el `select` y no en las `option`

```js
//Json de ejemplo
json_str=`{"Materias":[
 {"Clave":"Materia1"},
  {"Clave":"Materia2"},
  {"Clave":"Materia3"}
]}`;
json_data = JSON.parse(json_str);
var options = '';
$(json_data["Materias"]).each(function(){
  $('#recargado').append($('<option>').text(this.Clave).attr('value', this.Clave));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-field col s12" id="materias">
                <select id="recargado" name="materias">
                    <option id="disabled" value="" disabled selected>Elige la materia a consultar</option>
                    <?php require_once("materias.php"); ?>
                </select>
                <label>Materia que deseas consultar</label>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Le hice varios cambios a tu codigo.  Es un poco confuso porque faltan elementos HTML.  Ademas parece que quieres agregar mas opciones al cambiar en el mismo select, pero la idea seria algo asi:

```js
$("#recargado").change(function () {
let carrera = document.getElementById("carrera").value;

$.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1ah6wg", { idcarrera: carrera })
  .done(function (json_data) {        
    var options = '';
    $.each(json_data, function (i, json) {      
      $("#recargado").append('<option value="' + json.clave + '">' + json.nombre + '</option>');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-field col s12" id="materias">
                <select id="recargado" name="materias">
                    <option value="" selected></option>
                    <option value="">Elige la materia a consultar</option>
                    <?php require_once("materias.php"); ?>
                </select>
                <label>Materia que deseas consultar</label>
                <input id="carrera" value=1>
            </div>
```

Comment: Lo que sucede es que tengo dos select: uno donde tengo un listado de carreras (`id=carreras`), y otro, donde debo cargar las materias según la carrera que se seleccione (`id=recargado`), por eso es que en el change tengo el id carrera y, en el each, el recargado. Para ello, hice un json a partir de una consulta PHP y ese resultado es el que deseo poner como options del select con el `id=recargado`. He probado el each que me mencionas, sin embargo, obtengo los mismos resultados. @alanfcm